# How can I format dates in Javascript according to the OS date format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, operating-system, date-format

I'm developing an AngularJS application and we want to display dates in the same format as the user's OS. For example, my OS shows the date as YYYY-MM-DD, so I would like dates to be displayed in the same format.

I tried using `toLocalDateString(navigator.language)` but this gives me a date format of DD/MM/YYYY, not at all what my OS shows.

Any help is greatly appreciated.